# Is there a way to make different file managers have different bookmarks on the left bar? on Ubuntu 22

Tags: filemanager

If I have nautilus and nemo, for example. Can I make the two have different bookmarks?

I know the bookmarks for file managers are stored in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`, so that's why different file managers show the same bookmarks. But can it be changed?

Comment: this might work: create a copy of  `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` for both sets and a script for each filemanager; have the script copy the one you want over `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` and have it start the manager using an absolute path. Put the script somewhere in the beginning of PATH so it is found 1st.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is open source software, there always is a way editing source code. Have one of the file managers point to a different configuration file and recompile.

For end users, however, there is no easy way to change that behavior. Both file managers are programmed to store and retrieve the bookmarks from the same configuration file. For a majority of users, this ensures consistency where their bookmarks are preserved even if they use a different file manager.